# How to delete runtime import cache in deno?

Tags: node.js, deno

In node.js we can use

```js
delete require.cache[require.resolve(somePath)];
```

to delete the require cache in runtime.

Is there a similar way to delete runtime import cache in deno?

Answer (score 17):

The `-r` or `--reload` option will recompile the imported modules.

```
-r, --reload=<CACHE_BLACKLIST>     Reload source code cache (recompile TypeScript)
```

https://deno.land/manual#other-key-behaviors

> Other key behaviors
>
> - Remote code is fetched and cached on first execution, and never updated until the code is run with the --reload flag. (So, this will
>     still work on an airplane.)
> - Modules/files loaded from remote URLs are intended to be immutable and cacheable.

You can pass arguments to reload specific modules:

```
--reload=https://deno.land/std
```

https://deno.land/manual/linking_to_external_code/reloading_modules

Comment: what is runtime cache

Answer (score 8):

So far I have not found a command that clears the cache. But it is possible to get the current cache directories from deno using `deno info`. The output will look like this:

```
DENO_DIR location: "/Users/tgm/Library/Caches/deno"
Remote modules cache: "/Users/tgm/Library/Caches/deno/deps"
Emitted modules cache: "/Users/tgm/Library/Caches/deno/gen"
Language server registries cache: "/Users/tgm/Library/Caches/deno/registries"
```

So deleting the files inside `DENO_DIR` directory, clear the cache.
Hope this is helpful.

Answer (score 4):

Add a random querystring to the path, be sure to keep the correct extname:

```
const ext = path.extname(somePath);
const mod = (await import(`${somePath}?version=${Math.random()}${ext}`)).default;
```

It also support local file path like `const somePath = '../foo.tsx';`

Answer (score 2):

Deno supports *dynamic imports* since August '19, what I think you can do is something like

```
let neededModule = getNeededModule();
import neededModule;
...
neededModule  = getAnotherModule(); //Replace in runtime
import neededModule
...
//Or even delete in runtime (with some help from the garbage collector)
neededModule = null;
```